# How do I import css-mediaquery in Typescript?

Tags: css, typescript, node-modules, react-testing-library

I am currently trying to import css-mediaquery in Typescript like so:
`import { match } from 'css-mediaquery'`

However, I get this error:
`Cannot find module 'css-mediaquery' from '../../../TestFile.test.tsx`

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using typescript and needed to install `@types/css-mediaquery` as well. That fixed my problem.